# Displaying a video file on a website

Tags: video, browser, mp4, ogg, mov

I have a website that will involve the user uploading a video file which can then be viewed on the website, will i have to convert the file into different formats so it can be viewed in different browsers? or can i just play mp4, ogg and mov files on all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have few options.

1. Restrict user to upload only known/popular video format. Such as mp4,avi,3gp

**Chrome** = 3gp, .avi, .mov, .mp4, .m4v, .m4a, .mp3, .mkv, .ogv, .ogm, .ogg, .oga, .webm, .wav

**Firefox** = mp4, WebM, Ogg.

**IE** = mp4, no Ogg

**Safari** = mp4, no Ogg.

2. use FFmpeg converter to convert any non supportive format to mp4. Most browsers can play mp4 format.

http://www.ffmpeg.org/